# Mysql View vs Query performance

Tags: mysql, performance, view, query-optimization

I have a base query which uses a view which uses another view, like this.

```
SELECT a,b,c,DEBIT_AMOUNT, CREDIT_AMOUNT FROM MAIN_VIEW WHERE a='foo' AND c='bar';
```

Here's the schema

```
create table BASE_TABLE (
id int not null auto_increment,
a varchar(20),
b varchar(20),
c varchar(20),
primary key (id));

create table OTHER_TABLE (
oid int not null auto_increment,
id int not null,
mtype varchar(10),
amount varchar(20),
primary key (oid));

create or replace  view `MAIN_VIEW` AS 
SELECT  BT.a, BT.b, BT.c,SUB_VIEW.DEBIT_AMOUNT, SUB_VIEW.CREDIT_AMOUNT
    FROM  BASE_TABLE BT
    LEFT JOIN  SUB_VIEW  ON SUB_VIEW.id = BT.id

create or replace  view `SUB_VIEW` AS 
SELECT  BT.id, 
      ( SELECT  SUM(O.amount)
            FROM  OTHER_TABLE O
            WHERE  O.mtype = 'DR'
              AND  O.id = BT.id 
      ) AS DEBIT_AMOUNT, 
      ( SELECT  SUM(O.amount)
            FROM  OTHER_TABLE O
            WHERE  O.mtype = 'CR'
              AND  O.id = BT.id 
      ) AS CREDIT_AMOUNT
    FROM  BASE_TABLE BT
```

My query is permformance is very slow, to speed up query execution, i've modified the MAIN_VIEW like this
since the BASE_TABLE is already available on MAIN_VIEW, i thought fetching  DEBIT_AMOUNT and CREDIT_AMOUNT from then and there rather than going into the SUB_VIEW

> -- MAIN_VIEW ---

```
create or replace  view `MAIN_VIEW` AS 
SELECT  BT.a, BT.b, BT.c, 
      ( SELECT  SUM(O.amount)
            FROM  OTHER_TABLE O
            WHERE  O.mtype = 'DR'
              AND  O.id = BT.id 
      ) AS DEBIT_AMOUNT, 
      ( SELECT  SUM(O.amount)
            FROM  OTHER_TABLE O
            WHERE  O.mtype = 'CR'
              AND  O.id = BT.id 
      ) AS CREDIT_AMOUNT
    FROM  BASE_TABLE BT
```

But after this modification, query performance is even worse.. can any one help? I thought subviews are be bad for performance...

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: In addition, questions concerning query performance require, as a minimum,  CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables and the results of the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Okay, i've modified the question with schema.. having tough time with formatting

Answer (score 0):

You need `INDEX(id, mtype)` (in either order).  This should make the subqueries faster, hence the entire query faster.